# MongoDb/GeoJson: MultiPolygon vs GeometryCollection containing only polygons

Tags: mongodb, geospatial, geojson, spatial-index

I'm collecting location information from different sources and storing everything in a MongoDb collection. Apart from point locations with a single lat/lng coordinates, I'm also storing areas.

Now, one data gives me the location information as `GeometryCollection` but with all elements being `Polygons`. Another data source gives me the location as `MultiPolygon`. While I'm actually considering have a collection for each data source, I'm wondering which approach is better in the whole.

`GeometryCollection` is certainly more flexible, but maybe `MultiPolygon` shows better query performance (given that I always create a `2dspehere` index over the location field). Is it worth it to convert one representation into the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good news:  query performance and indexability are the same in MongoDB for all supported GeoJSON types.

The main driver in your decision should be whether your info architecture for the geo field and the software that consumes it needs to contain more types than just polygons.  You say you're storing point locations?   If you want to hold all geo data in a single field e.g. `location` (and likely with a 2dsphere index on that) then you will need `GeometryCollection` into which you can put `Point`and the `MultiPolygon`.   It is recommended in the GeoJSON spec https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#page-9 **not** to nest `GeometryCollection` so for those data sources giving you a `GeometryCollection`, you would iterate the contents and populate your own `GeometryCollection` which also holds your `Point`s etc.

If you are storing points separately, e.g. `eventCenter` as separate from `eventAreasEffected`, then the `eventCenter` can be just a `Point` and the `eventAreasEffected` can be a single 'MultiPolygon'; no need for `GeometryCollection`.  It is perfectly fine to have geo in more than one field, and to have or not have multiple 2dsphere indexes on these fields.   Starting in MongoDB 4.0, you can use `$geoNear` on a collection that has more than one 2dsphere index by including the `key` option.

Here's an unofficial but reasonable definitional approach:  A `MultiPolygon` is not an arbitrary collection of `Polygon` but rather a single "shape concept" that happens to have disjoint polygons.  The United States can be described in a single `MultiPolygon` that has Alaska, Hawaii, the continental US, maybe Puerto Rico, etc.    In fact, to this end, you'll note that it is a little trickier to store data relevant to each member of the `MultiPolygon` because `coordinates` can only be an array of arrays of points.  Information about the third polygon, for example, has to be carried in a peer field to the single toplevel `coordinates` field.   But a discrete array of `Polygon` or a `GeometryCollection` of `Polygon` can store extra information in **each** shape.  Note that neither GeoJSON nor MongoDB restrict you from adding fields in addition to `type` and `coordinates` for each shape.

A more subtle issue is the design and semantics of a `GeometryCollection` of `Polygon` vs. `MultiPolygon`.  To further complicate it, there is the issue of explicit holes defined in the `Polygon` vs. a collection of implicitly "layered" `Polygon` that are post-processed outside of the DB by geo software.

Comment: That's a very comprehensive and useful answer! Thanks for that! Regarding the design of the database, I'm currently using 2 collections: (a) one for points where every location field is `Point` and (b) one for areas where the location field is `MultiPolygon` (if there's only one polygon the length of the array is just 1). Right now I don't assume I will have individual information for each shape/polygon in a `MultiPolygon` but your point is valid. I'm not married to the current design -- particularly using 2 instead 1 collection -- but it's good to know that performance is less of a factor.

Answer (score 0):

the problem with this subject is that there isnt a good answer.
its all about what you will prefer or need. here is a great answer written on stackExchange.

**Polygon vs MultiPolygon**
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225368/understanding-difference-between-polygon-and-multipolygon-for-shapefiles-in-qgis

and i dont know about GeometryCollection so cant tell you anything about that. but this link will reveal alot of information to you.

Comment: The differences between the different types in a conceptual level seems rather intuitive. My questions refers a bit more for a implementation/performance point of view. `GeometryCollection` simply allows to put polygons, lines and points into the same location object. This allows, of course that `GeometryCollection` may contain only polygons, which, as a far as I can tell makes it conceptually the same as a `MultiPolygon` object. I only wonder if there a performance differences when it comes to querying large collections using those location types.

Comment: i would convert everything to a multipolygon object. as it seems that a geometryCollection contains a multipolygon object. so by that logic a multipolygon would by option to choose.

Comment: > For type "MultiPolygon", each element in the coordinates array is a coordinates array as described for type "Polygon".
A GeoJSON geometry object with type "GeometryCollection" is a geometry object which represents a collection of geometry objects.
A geometry collection must have a member with the name "geometries". The value corresponding to "geometries" is an array. Each element in this array is a GeoJSON geometry object.